# How to load RecyclerView items step by step in NestedScrollView?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have gallery page in my project. There are RecyclerView, ScrollView and other basic views in gallery page. My RecyclerView loads all images when open the page. This causes the app to freeze. I want to use RecyclerView feature like load items part by part.

Actually my XML is too long so I didn't add some views in following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        tools:context=".DetailActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/detail_fragment_constraint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:scrollbars="none">
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_category"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_image" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_category"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/feed_detail_category" />

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/feed_detail_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/feed_detail_category" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/comment_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/no_comment_text" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: Here's your problem: `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`. When you use wrap content, everything will be loaded, and the viewholders are not really getting recycled. You need to define a fixed height or use `match_parent` if the parent has a fixed height.

Comment: When you use a recyclerview inside a nestedscrollview the views are never recycled and instead all viewholders are loaded in to memory at the same time which is what is causing your app to freeze

Comment: Thanks for answers, you right but when i try to scroll my gallery page, i want to scroll all page views. As you know i can scroll only recycler view or all views(if i can scroll all view recycler view's doesnt work as my want). I think i should ask another question about that.